# ffmpeg cannot recognize the '-af' option

Tags: ffmpeg

The ffmpeg cannot recognize the '-af' option. How can I fix this?

```
$ ffmpeg -i 01.wav -af pan=1:c0=c1 01mono.wav
ffmpeg version 0.10.12-7:0.10.12-1~precise1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 09:49:36 with gcc 4.6.3
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.12-1~precise1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[wav @ 0x19dd680] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510
Input #0, wav, from '01.wav':
  Duration: 00:40:20.40, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Unrecognized option 'af'
Failed to set value 'pan=1:c0=c1' for option 'af'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old. See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page and get a static build, or refer to a [compile guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide). [FFmpeg development is very active](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=shortlog), so it is recommended to always use a recent build.